How do I copy over static files to a firebase function
I have a nuxt 2.0 application in an Azure Devops Pipeline and being published to firebase.
In my deployment, I'm trying to copy over the static assets to the functions, but I can't get them to deploy. What is the right linux code to copy over the static assets? It is working for the application..just not the functions.
So for the application, this is working: cp -a static/. public/
But for the functions, this is not working: cp -a static/. public/_nuxt

Try with cp -a static public/_nuxt/. rather.

Thank you kissu, but that did not work.

So your actual query is how to copy the deployed files after the app deployment via Azure Pipelines?

No, this is in the pre deployment in the firebase json. In particular:      "predeploy": [
"rm -rf public/* && mkdir -p public/_nuxt && cp -r .nuxt/dist/client/ public/_nuxt && cp -a static/. public/ && cp -a static/. public/_nuxt"
],

Quite a few things being moved here, does it work as expected if you try it locally?
